# Invalid Tenancy Name

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I am working on an ASP.NET Boilerplate service project.

When I am saving a client, it returns an error:

> Tenancy Name is not valid

The tenancy name contains spaces.
`TenantDto` maps to `Tenant` object without any error. Database table `TenancyName` column is `nvarchar(64)`. Error occurs when it is saving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation on [Tenant Management](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Tenant-Management#tenant-entity):

> AbpTenant class defines some base properties, most important ones are:
>
> - **TenancyName**: This is **unique** name of a tenant in the application. It should not be changed normally. It can be used to allocate subdomains to tenants like '**mytenant**.mydomain.com'. Tenant.**TenancyNameRegex** constant defines the naming rule.
> - **Name**: An arbitrary, human-readable, long name of the tenant.

[`TenancyNameRegex`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/9ff01eb5e23820700e9455f3432bd61a97b484b4/src/Abp.Zero.Common/MultiTenancy/AbpTenantBase.cs#L34) is `"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,}$"` as spaces are not allowed in subdomains.

As quoted above, use `Name` for the human-readable name (with spaces) of the tenant.

Comment: I commented TenancyNameRegex  annotation still i m getting that error

Comment: I commented regular  expression annotation

Comment: TenancyNameRegex shouldn't be removed. You are saying like "I removed the brakes but my car still crashes" :)

Answer (score 1):

Before saving a tenant, it's being validated against **TenancyNameRegex** regular expression.  Thus a tenant name cannot contain space (by design).
Do not remove the regex check, but add a client-side validation to check the tenant name.

```
protected virtual Task ValidateTenancyNameAsync(string tenancyName)
{
    if (!Regex.IsMatch(tenancyName, AbpTenant<TUser>.TenancyNameRegex))
    {
         throw new UserFriendlyException(L("InvalidTenancyName"));
    }

    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

See the code  =>  https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/45fe6d9f38b79ab111eaf2a54b507b87c92e544e/src/Abp.Zero.Common/MultiTenancy/AbpTenantManager.cs#L222